# Text along a Peano Curve in LaTeX for cover page

Tags: tikz-pgf, text

Good afternoon,

I was trying to write text ALONG a peano curve, and I looked up how to draw a peano curve with TikZ.

However, I don't know how to place the text on the peano curve itself. I am stuck and I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.

This is the code that I have for generating peano curves. I really wish I understood TikZ better, it is such a powerful package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[position=top,labelformat=empty]{subfig}
\newdimen\HilbertLastX
\newdimen\HilbertLastY
\newcounter{HilbertOrder}

\def\DrawToNext#1#2{%
   \advance \HilbertLastX by #1
   \advance \HilbertLastY by #2
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
   % Alternative implementation using plot streams:
   % \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
}

% \Hilbert[right_x,right_y,left_x,left_x,up_x,up_y,down_x,down_y]
\def\Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8] {
  \ifnum\value{HilbertOrder} > 0%
     \addtocounter{HilbertOrder}{-1}
     \Hilbert[#5,#6,#7,#8,#1,#2,#3,#4]
     \DrawToNext {#1} {#2}
     \Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8]
     \DrawToNext {#5} {#6}
     \Hilbert[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8]
     \DrawToNext {#3} {#4}
     \Hilbert[#7,#8,#5,#6,#3,#4,#1,#2]
     \addtocounter{HilbertOrder}{1}
  \fi
}


% \hilbert((x,y),order)
\def\hilbert((#1,#2),#3){%
   \advance \HilbertLastX by #1
   \advance \HilbertLastY by #2
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
   % Alternative implementation using plot streams:
   % \pgfplothandlerlineto
   % \pgfplotstreamstart
   % \pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfqpoint{\HilbertLastX}{\HilbertLastY}}
   \setcounter{HilbertOrder}{#3}
   \Hilbert[1mm,0mm,-1mm,0mm,0mm,1mm,0mm,-1mm]
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    % draw Hilbert curves of order n=1,...,5
    % Warning! Curves with order > 6 may crash TeX
    \subfloat[$n=1$]{\tikz[scale=18] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),1);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=2$]{\tikz[scale=6] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),2);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=3$]{\tikz[scale=2.6] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),3);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=4$]{\tikz[scale=1.2] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),4);}~~
    \subfloat[$n=5$]{\tikz[scale=0.58] \hilbert((0mm,0mm),5);}%
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```

To clarify: I dont want text ABOVE the path, I want the document written along the peano filling curve path. I know how to do some shapes.

I was hoping somebody could help me find a solution.

This is an example of something similar, of some text along a path. 
I just don't know at all how to apply this to the Peano curve.

(You need to use `XeLaTeX` to load this one, I was working with some weird fonts and in thai as well, so this example is in Thai

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, margin = 2cm, headsep = .5cm,headheight=50pt,xetex]{geometry}\usepackage[main = english,thai]{babel}


\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{txfonts,pxfonts}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\begin{document}


\resizebox{\textwidth}{\textwidth}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    width = \textwidth,
  decoration={
    reverse path,
    text effects along path,
    text={Let me know when you are able to use word to do this and I will stop using LaTeX and I will promise you I will never talk about it again. However if you ever think you will be able to do somethign like this in word... haahaha, 
    good luck being able to get it done in a feasable amount of time. },
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      character count=\i, character total=\n, color=green!50!red,
      characters={scale=0.5-0.45*\i/\n}
    }
]
\draw [decorate] (0,0) 
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=(\i/3000)^2+ sin(3*\i)*cos(2*\i)/10;}] in {0,5,...,2800}{ -- (\i:\r)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\end{document}
```

EDIT1: Clarified some points to make the question some clear, and added an extra example.

EDIT2: Some formatting bugs (Sorry, I am new to stackexchange).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You haven't any tree in your document nor any overlapping of images. Above images are present $n=1$, ... $n=4$. What exactly is your problem? Caption to your images (which is not present)?

Comment: When I compile your MWE, I do get text "n=1" and others placed above the Hilbert curves.  So I don't know exactly what your question is about.  Can you draw an image what exactly you want to have?

Comment: Hello, I added extra code to clarify: What I want is to write instead of the lines in the peano curve, to place text along the curve. To create some kind of artistic cover for a document about fractals.

Comment: @A.Recuenco: typing text along the path of the Hilbert curves is a problem, I can't help you.  I beg your pardon.  (The target should be much clearer now!)  But still have one question: how about your title "Forest Tree, using images - Overlapping"  I am still concerned about the addressed problem there ...

Comment: @Jan: I am afraid I don't know how to change the title. 
The title was indeed suppose to be different, but I was leaving work on a rush and forgot to change the title EDIT: It wasn't that difficult to change the title, sorry about that, I hope you forgive my "noob" mistakes

Comment: @A.Recuenco Hey, no problem at all.  Every thing is fine now, and we both learned a bit.  Highfive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an explicit construction of Hilbert curve in the manual. All I did is copying the example code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Hilbert curve}{
  \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
  \symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnright} % Explicitly define + and - symbols.
  \symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
  \rule{A -> +BX-AXA-XB+}
  \rule{B -> -AX+BXB+XA-}
}
\tikz
    \draw[
        rounded corners=10pt,scale=5,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.},
        },
        decorate,
        lindenmayer system={
            Hilbert curve, axiom=A, order=4, angle=90
        },
    ]
    lindenmayer system
;

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! :) Simple and in the manual :P
I am still having issues understanding the rule system. That is why I was trying to solve the problem using other approaches, but it seems that if I had tried to put a bit more thought into the lienmann library it would've worked very easily

Answer (score 4):

As a follow up, and following on @Symbol 1 solution I wanted to post a complete solution of what I wanted, in case it serves any purpose for anyone else. Since I think it may be more "general" and it touches on some other tikz keys.

Rounding corners seem to create a lot of overhall, hence why I had to remove it to be able to go up to order 5

To change the repeating text for a custom long text, remove the key "repeat text" and replace the chinese text for your own long text

(I am using XeLaTeX because of the chinese "Happy New Year" text, but this can be easily changed)

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usepackage{xcolor} %To use the colors
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,math} % math library to evaluate the color transition (key evaluate on tikz) 

\definecolor{chinesegolden}{RGB}{%
246,180,72}
\definecolor{chinesered}{RGB}{%
198, 0, 20}

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Hilbert curve}{
  \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
  \symbol{+}{\pgflsystemturnright} % Explicitly define + and - symbols.
  \symbol{-}{\pgflsystemturnleft}
  \rule{A -> +BX-AXA-XB+}
  \rule{B -> -AX+BXB+XA-}
}



\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=2, decoration={
    text effects along path,
    text={ 新 年 快 乐 ! 新 年 快 乐 ! ! !},
        text effects/.cd,
        repeat text, %Fills the whole curve
      character count=\i, character total=\n,
      characters={evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;}, 
                scale=0.3, 
            text along path,
                text ={chinesered!\c!chinesegolden}
            }
    }
]    
\path[
        decorate, %text effects={group letters},
        lindenmayer system={
            Hilbert curve, axiom=A, order = 5, angle=90 %Order 5 takes a while to render
        },
    ]
    lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Order 5 - Hilbert Curve with text along it]